# Check the Succesfull Copy of a File

Tags: java, android, file, corruption, copying

I am trying to make a file manager app in Android.

I want to provide the user with an option to move their files. So first I am copying the Files then I am deleting the file if there is no error.

This is the code I am using to copy the files

```
public static boolean copy(File copy, String directory, Context con) {
   static FileInputStream inStream = null;
   static OutputStream outStream = null;
   DocumentFile dir = getDocumentFileIfAllowedToWrite(new File(directory), con);
   String mime = "";
   DocumentFile copy1 = dir.createFile(mime, copy.getName());

   try {
      inStream = new FileInputStream(copy);
      outStream = con.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(copy1.getUri());
      byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
         outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      try {
         inStream.close();
         outStream.close();
         return true;
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

But in one of my devices the files are simply getting deleted without copying.

So my thought is that I will check the length of the file by `SourceFile.length(`) and the length of the `DestinationFile.length()` if both are same or not. If both are same then I will delete the SourceFile.

Is the most effective way to check it without checking the MD5 of an File? Also what are the chances that the file transfer is incomplete/corrupted and still the length is same?

Comment: cCmparing the file length does not guarantee you no corruption. MD5 is the most reliable approach, imho.

Comment: @Herr Derb Thanks for the answer. Just an another idea should I try to transfer a test text file first say with the text "test" inside and then try and check if the matter of the new text file is equal to "test" and if so then I can transfer the other media files. Also can you please explain the reason generally leading to corruption of file? Please post an answer also for me to accept it.

Comment: This only guarantees that the test file was submitted successfully, but will say nothing about the transmission of other files.

Comment: @HerrDerb OK. Thanks can you please post an answer so that I can accept it.